# Join values in 2 separate arrays within an array of objects and display them as one array

Tags: typescript

I have an array like so:

```
const books[{
    name: 'book1',
    id: '1',
    fromStatus: [{
        name: 'Available',
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Free',
        id: 2
    }],
    toStatus: [{
        name: 'Not available',
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Not free',
        id: 2
    }]
}, {
    name: 'book2',
    id: '2',
    fromStatus: [{
        name: 'Burnt',
        id: 1
    }],
    toStatus: [{
        name: 'Not burnt',
        id: 1
    }]
}]
```

I'd like to create a new array, which looks like this:

```
const statusFromTo[{
    {
        id: 1,
        fromStatusName: 'Available',
        toStatusName: 'Not available'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        fromStatusName: 'Burnt',
        toStatusName: 'Not burnt'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        fromStatusName: 'Free',
        toStatusName: 'Not free'
    },
}]
```

The from and to status' would be matched on their id's. For example Free and Not Free both have an id of 3, Available and Not Available both have an id of 1, Burnt and Not Burnt both have an id of 2.

I've tried various different forEach's and .map's but can't seem to crack it. Any help? Using typescript!

Comment: Where does `id`: `3` come from? In your example, `Free` and `Not Free` both have an `id` of `2`, but the description in your question says that they have an `id` of `3`.

Comment: in the NEW array, they would need unique ids, if they kept their old ones there would be conflicting ids

Answer (score 0):

Try this [(Playground link)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=26&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARiEBrCMC8MDaBvAUDAmMAQwFsBTALhgHIFkBGGgGn0IEsATamp1wmADMATiFIBlKMSgBXCNRxsBBEhR4BBAG7F2AG2Jxd5FkuVdqDUwF9mMPMsKqqtAGLDyx-g5jmYAJmsAXS8CKBBJaTkFe28nHgA5EFhibT0DIxNvH24YSwEbO1MBONpE2BEPTO9fAPzA3AKYlTJnOkQkPyqCXxpOkKFRCSlZeSwm5RKaACEZYTAoLrMcvMIrYNMwiJHooscWhKT4WfnFgV8VgjWG+txQSFhoSIg3MQAVEHR4dogAOlJiAAOAAo4OgAHzwH4iMRbOR-QFAoHQoZPWzsACU4JgQMwyNhvyctjgP02wzkmHYgR+TkC6Lpph+7k4MmA5ERAPcmlswFmwkxaAhmB+wo55C5MGFPx5wmEwSwtIZ-2BOLxZIgtlJTzlXH5EKB2C4tlVqJgmpGVnpt3AEBARh+uhAAHMgY8Ri9SO90bggA):

```
const books = [{
    name: 'book1',
    id: '1',
    fromStatus: [{
        name: 'Available',
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Free',
        id: 2
    }],
    toStatus: [{
        name: 'Not available',
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Not free',
        id: 2
    }]
}, {
    name: 'book2',
    id: '2',
    fromStatus: [{
        name: 'Burnt',
        id: 1
    }],
    toStatus: [{
        name: 'Not burnt',
        id: 1
    }]
}]

const statusFromTo = books.map(b => b.fromStatus.map((fromStatus, i) => ([fromStatus.name, b.toStatus[i].name])))
    .reduce((prev, curr) => [...prev, ...curr], [])
    .map(([fromStatus, toStatus], id) => ({id, fromStatus, toStatus}))

console.log(statusFromTo)
```

This code still makes a few assumptions - specifically, it assumes that for the `fromStatus` and `toStatus` arrays for each item in the `books` array:

- they will have the same length
- the items at the same position within each array will have the same `id` value

If these arrays could be different lengths and/or the items could be in different orders (based on their `id` property), you'd need to account for that. But based on the example data you've provided, this code should produce a `statusFromTo` array that looks the way you expect, with a unique `id` value for each entry.

Comment: Hmm i like the thought but would it work if there were multiple from and to status' in each of their respective arrays?

Comment: Yeah, that's what my comment at the end of my answer was saying - you'd need to account for that. How would you expect that to be handled? You might need to add some more details to your question.

Comment: Thanks, edited. It would be matching them on their object id's so fromStatus.id = toStatus.id

Comment: @cking888 Okay, see edit. Still has a few edge cases for you to deal with, but should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Thank you, i'll give it a go tomorrow and if it sets me up mark this as the answer :)